# Getting more than one possition though code (unity c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i made a "turret" in unity that shoots automatically on enemies it works with one enemy but when i put 2 it shoots in the midle of then dont know why it does that

```
public transform enemy;

public void Update() {
   enemy = Gameobject.FindgameObjectWithTag("Enemy").getComponent<Transform>;
   //just put the getting the possition part because the shooting works just fine
}
```

Comment: It would help to see some more code, like a [mcve].

Comment: it probably just switches between them?

Comment: just because the shooting part works fine doesn't mean you shouldn't add it. With this I can't tell what thje problem is because I have no clue what it does with this enemy variable.

Comment: The function Gameobject.FindgameObjectWithTag("Enemy") returns the same game object until this object was destroyed or disabled. I don't think it switches between them. @derHugo

Comment: @LuuSang there is no guarantee that it will be the same object .. we don't know what it does exactly in the backend and whether it goes by hierarchy or "came alive" time .. so a change in the hierarchy order might already change the returned value

Comment: @derHugo yes, that is right

Answer (score 1):

Your script is refreshing the enemy position every `Update()` iteration.
Try to have the turret stick to the enemy until it gets out of range, or until it is dead. Before doing your variable assignation, check if `enemy != null`, if it is the case, then you can write :

`enemy = Gameobject.FindgameObjectWithTag("Enemy").getComponent<Transform>;`

Also, try to avoid refreshing every `Update()` call, instead, use a different function that you call every half second.

I recommend you checking this project by Brackeys, that handles the situation perfectly. [Here](https://github.com/Brackeys/Tower-Defense-Tutorial)

GLHF